# WebView doesnt appear when compiling for API 29

Tags: java, android

I developed a JAVA app for Android 9 (API 28). When i tried putting it in the play store google demanded it must be API 29 and above. So i recompiled for API 29, when i tested it at API 29, the WebView im using in the app stopped working, it worked perfectly for API 28.

Im simply using the webview for displaying simple locally generated HTML text string containing a text table and a jpg, but with API 29 it doesnt even show up on the screen, or is blank.

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient_rect"
    style="@style/MyLayoutBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:visibility="visible" />
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code snippet (most of irrelevant stuff removed)

```
 public WebView webView;
 webView= (WebView) convertView.findViewById(com.app.mine.R.id.webView);
 string html="see below"; << REPLACE THIS LINE WITH HTML BELOW
 webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

There were no code changes from version 28 to 29, i dont know what caused the WebView to stop working. I spent the whole day trying to figure it out.

I read that google changed the WebView implementation from chrome to TriChrome in Android 10, dont know if that's causing it. I also read somewhere that google had a bug in their chrome update which caused the browser to crash, so I uninstalled that update from my phone but still my WebView doesnt work in 29.

The phone im using is android 10 by the way and it doesnt work on that. But if i compile the same code for API 28 it works, but google refuses API 28 for play store apps. So that means i cant publish the app because they demand 29 but it only works on 28 for some reason.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I figured out the problem, it was the HTML i was using, my original post didnt contain the actual HTML i was trying to display in the WebView. Turns out API 29 has problems with the < STYLE > tag. By removing that it worked.

Below is a sample of the HTML im trying to display in the WebView. Simply adding or removing the entire < STYLE > tag section made it work/not work in API 29, however API 28 works all the time even with a very complex < STYLE > tag i was using originally. So there must be a bug in the API 29 WebView.

```
<html>
<style>
    table {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #633;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
        background: #eaebec;
        margin: 5px;
        border: #ccc 1px solid;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    }
</style>
<table>   
  <tr>      
   <th>Company</th>
   <th>Contact</th>    
   <th>Country</th>   
 </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: The recent WebView crashing issue, should be resolved by updating to latest on device (i.e. if Gmail doesn't work, then that would be the same issue). 1) What logs are showing up when you run on API 29. 2) Test on emulator - same or different? 3) If webview rendering problem see: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: @Morrison Chang, thanks for the message, i dont see any messages jumping out saying the WebView crashed on the log cat, and the same happens on the emulator. Dont know why there would be a rendering problem on API 29 and not 28, but it seems the WebView isnt even present on the screen at all

Comment: Not sure why you have a linear layout in a linear layout (perhaps additional content not in question), as well as `convertView` in your code. Try a very simple layout so that you know that part works unless the question is about a WebView in ListView.

Comment: @programmer3 Your code snippet worked on my Android 10 (API-29) phone.

Comment: I discovered what was causing the problem, please see the UPDATE in my original post